# "This type is final so it cannot be inherited from" - ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I"m trying to extend the [`ViewPager2`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) class so I can allow dragging my `SeekBarPreference` left and right.

```
class ViewPager2Custom(context: Context) : ViewPager2(context) {

}
```

However I'm getting a "This type is final so it cannot be inherited from" red line on my `ViewPager2(context)`.

Any idea?

Comment: Well, it's like the message says. The class is final so you cannot extend it.

Comment: The link you have added Says its define as `public final class ViewPager2` .. And you can not extends a final class ..

Comment: Any idea how I can prevent the viewpager from executing when I swipe left/right on my `SeekBarPreference`?

Answer (score 0):

The NestedScrollableHost class does exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt

The basic idea is that you override `onInterceptTouchEvent` and request the parent of the NestedScrollableHost (in this case the `ViewPager2`) to disallow it to intercept touch events, through the `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` method.

```
// Pseudo-code for NestedScrollableHost

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    handleInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

private void handleInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Early return if parent viewpager is null or child can't scroll in same direction as parent
    if (getParentViewPager() == null ||
            (!canChildScrollVertically(-1f) && !canChildScrollVertically(1f))) {
        return;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        // You can tailor your class to handle the event in the way you want to,
        // e.g. do something on down and move events:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Disallow the parent (and all subsequent parents) to intercept touch events.
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallow);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Some other logic.
    }
}
```

You would place the NestedScrollableHost in between your `ViewPager2` and (in your case) `SeekBarPreference` in your XML.